# (+r) vs. (=r) constraints in GCC x86 Inline Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have a problem with a piece of code in c that uses an inline assembly block to sort an array.

My complete code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 20

int main()
{
    int array[n];
    int i;
    int swapped;

    printf("Enter the elements one by one \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Input array elements \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    /*  Bubble sorting begins */   
    do
    {
          swapped = 0;
          for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
          {
/* 
           if (array[i] < array [i-1])
           {
               swapped =1;
               int temp = array [i-1];
               array [i-1] = array [i];
               array[i] = temp;
           }
*/

               //body of the for loop
               //converted to assembly
               __asm__ __volatile__("cmp %0, %1;"
                                    "jge DONE;"
                                    "mov eax, %0;"
                                    "mov %0, %1;"
                                    "mov %1, eax;"
                                    "mov %2, 1;"
                                    "DONE: "
                                    : "+r" (array[i]), "+r" (array[i-1]), "=r" (swapped)
                                    : //no input
                                    : "eax", "cc"
                                    );


          }

    } while (swapped > 0);

    printf("Sorted array is...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason the do while becomes an infinite loop, but when I change the modifier for `swapped` variable to **`"+r" (swapped)`** it works. I looked at the generated assembly code (-save-temp) for both scenarios and didn't notice anything other than moving the `swapped` variable to a register in the case that "+r" is used, which is expected.

Why do I need to use `"+r"`?

Comment: I would be scared of writing a jump like that. Imagine the compiler unrolls the loop, where is this going to jump to? Also, why write inline asm for this? The compiler should generate better from the C code.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-masm=intel`? I can't see your command line.

Comment: Well, my only purpose here is to learn GCC inline assembly. Moreover I've used __volatile__ and compiled the code with -O0, just to prevent these kinds of optimizations.

Comment: If you are concerned about expansions, you can use %=, like this: `jge DONE%=;` and `DONE%=:`.  This will be expanded to a unique number (see "Other format strings" under https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate). Also, you might find the code easier to read if you use symbolic names (ie change `"=r" (swapped)` to `[swapped] "=r" (swapped)`, then use `%[swapped]` instead of %2). Lastly, if you use gcc -S to output the asm, you will see your commands all run together.  Consider using `\n\t` instead of `;`. FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `=` that means it's an output and it must be written. However, you only write it in case there was a swap. The compiler will optimize away the `swapped = 0` that you used, because it assumes the assembler block will produce a new value that will overwrite it. This means, if there was no swap the compiler will happily use whatever garbage is in the register that it has chosen for the `%2` as the new value for `swapped`, and that, by chance, produces an endless loop.

Here is some code to illustrate:

```
swapped = 0;
/* this is the asm block */
{
    /* this is not initialized, because it's declared as output */
    int register_for_operand2;
    if (array[i] < array[i - 1])
    {
        /* body here */
        register_for_operand2 = 1;
    }
    /* the compiler generates this code for the output operand */
    /* this will copy uninitialized value if the above condition was false */
    swapped = register_for_operand2;
}
```

Comment: Correct. I just figured it out and was about to post the answer. Thanks!

Comment: While trying to debug it, I realized an strange behavior. The code still works "=r" (swapped) if I put a printf("\n"); right before evaluating the while condition. Just curious to know why?

Comment: As jester said, it's going to use the "garbage" that was in the register.  Apparently printf is (just by chance) leaving the value you want.  Obviously not behavior you want to depend upon...